# Partials functions as parameters and function parameter annotation

Tags: annotations, arguments, python-3.8, functools

Suppose we have a function that receives a callable as parameter:

```
def foo(bar: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> None:
    pass
```

According the annotation the callable we must pass as argument should receive only one argument and return anything, just like:

```
def third_party_callable(x: Any) -> None:
    pass
```

But we have our own callable that receives 2 arguments so we decide to use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#partial-objects) to match the `foo` signature:

```
def my_custom_callable(y: Any, x: Any) -> None:
    pass

my_callable = partial(my_custom_callable, 'my_custom_y')
# And then ...
foo(my_callable)
```

This will result in a linter warning stating that: *Expected type '(Any) -> None', got 'partial[None]' instead*

Question 1: Is there some way to do this and not getting the linter warning?

Question 2: Should the returned type of partial be `Callable[[...], ...]`?

Question 3: If what I want is not a desired behavior could someone explain why?